# OpenVPN and the NetworkManager plugin - Advanced Settings Questions

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I just set up OpenVPN and the network manager plugin.  I purchased VPN service from PrivateInternetAccess.com.  It works fine but only when the Cipher and HMAC Authentication under the advanced settings are set to "default".  When I run this VPN service on Mac and Windows I am able to adjust these settings.  But in Ubuntu 13.04 any setting changes from "default" results in a connection failure.

What are these "default" settings for the Cipher and HMAC?

Why can't I change them?

Answer (score 1):

### Works as designed

Cipher and HMAC settings must match the server settings exactly in OpenVPN. There's no negotiation in any way on those. I cannot elaborate on why it does work on another OS, but having different settings on client and server should not work.

If you need other HMAC and Cipher settings you'll have to change the server settings as well. In your case in which you purchase a service you don't have control over the server settings. Hence, you'll have to stick to the service supplied settings for your OpenVPN client.